# This question was closed as off topic. Where is its place?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, off-topic

[Are all web pages HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151709/are-all-web-pages-html)

I want to create a website but am just a beginner.

So where is its place?

Comment: Just a side note that may not apply specifically in your case: Stack Exchange does not have a site appropriate for *every* possible question.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Good point.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a **perfect** fit for Stack Overflow, but I think it's a good question with a good answer and it's worth keeping it. Voting to reopen... and it's reopened.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an interesting case.  It's a nut-n-bolts type question about website development, and I can see some arguments for it being considered a programming question.  However it's also a simple question with a very broad and open ended scope, so it's possible that even if it's on topic, it's not appropriate for the stackoverflow format.

I think you'd be better off going to chat.stackoverflow.com and asking a series of questions there.

Also, if you go through a few simple tutorials on developing web pages including HTML, CSS, Javascript, Java, and PHP you'd get your answer very quickly with not too much effort.

Comment: But to answer the question: HTML is a document format, like PDF in many ways.  The browser just asks the website for the page, and generally HTML is always returned.  However, the HTML page can also reference CSS, Javascript, Java, Flash, and other code which runs as a program inside the browser on the user's computer.  Complicating matters further, the web designer can write code that runs on the webserver - typically this code returns HTML to the browser.  But a webserver can serve all kinds of stuff, including HTML, images, CSS, and various forms of code.

Comment: That should give you a lot to think about, and probably the best way to get it all straight in your head is to install a webserver on your computer (check out WAMP or LAMP for possible easy-installs) and follow some tutorials for beginning web development.

Comment: I _did_ try to find the answer myself before posting it. For someone who already knows the answer it might look simple. For me, only after I saw the answers. (Which were very good.)

Comment: @Lix I still haven't gotten an answer for future cases. Even if chat can be considered the place for the question – I lack the reputation.

Answer (score 3):

I think this belongs on webmasters.stackexchange.com. I don't think it's too open ended and could be answered with a quick overview of static vs dynamic pages.

Comment: Good idea. I actually posted the question there _first_ http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25501/are-all-web-pages-html . But it was closed as off topic. :)